Special characters in \lstinline cause an error when used in tcbox

I am trying to create a tcolorbox style for LaTeX listings. Although listings styles work as desired, using \tcbox command with \

Improper alphabetic constant

Using { and } bracks causes the following errors

Argument of \lst@temp has an extra }


File ended while scanning use of \tcbox

My MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX-inline}{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle=\linespread{1}\ttfamily\color{black},
    literate=
    *{\{}{{\textcolor{gray}{\symbol{123}}}}{1} % {
        {\}}{{\textcolor{gray}{\symbol{125}}}}{1}, % }
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
}
\lstset{style=LaTeX-inline}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tcbNoSpaceBox}{}{NoSpaceBox}
\tcbset{\tcbNoSpaceBox/.style=
    {
        % inner spacings
        top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
        left=0pt, right=0pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        % oversize
        oversize,
        % rules
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable,
        % colors
        colframe=SpringGreen3, colback=Ivory1,
        % opacity
        opacityframe=0.75, opacityback=0.75,
        % text alignment
        box align=base, nobeforeafter,
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \tcbox[\tcbNoSpaceBox]{\lstinline|\\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|}
    
    \lstinline|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|
    
    \tcbox[\tcbNoSpaceBox]{\lstinline|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|} % improper alphabetic constant
    
    \tcbox[\tcbNoSpaceBox]{\lstinline|{\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|} % file ended while scanning use of \\tcbox
    
    \tcbox[\tcbNoSpaceBox]{\lstinline|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em}|} % argument of \lst@temp has an extra }
    
\end{document}


You shouldn't use \ in the name of the key. Instead of \tcbset{\tcbNoSpaceBox/.style= use \tcbset{tcbNoSpaceBox/.style=. And please provide complete code in examples.

However, if I add the minimum preamble necessary to avoid compilation errors unrelated to the one you report, your example compiles fine for me as-is, even with \tcbNoSpaceBox.

I've tested with TeX Live 2020–2024: As cfr already told in his comment it runs without error message. Testing older versions would not make sense, because the LaTeX versions of older TeX Live do not provide \NewDocumentCommand. So I guess, you are either using a mixture of incompatible LaTeX kernel and packages or you haven't told us all needed information. If I'm wrong, please show the log file.

@cfr. The example above works, but \lstinline|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em| and \lstinline|{\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em}| inside \tcbox do not

We can't use an example to debug which doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please edit your question so the code produces the problem.

@cfr I added a line of code for all cases with comments on the error type

Have a look at \NewTotalTCBox in the tcolorbox manual. It has examples how to create one for listings

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The solution does not solve my issue because I need { and } as inputs

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh It does solve the issue, because it does not need the {...} around the box contents.

As said in comments, create a suitable box with \NewTotalTCBox:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX-inline}{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle=\linespread{1}\ttfamily\color{black},
    literate=
    *{\{}{{\textcolor{gray}{\symbol{123}}}}{1} % {
        {\}}{{\textcolor{gray}{\symbol{125}}}}{1}, % }
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
}
\lstset{style=LaTeX-inline}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewTotalTCBox{\commandbox}{ v }{verbatim,colback=lightgray}{\lstinline{#1}}


\begin{document}
    
    \commandbox|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|
    
    \lstinline|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em|
    
    \commandbox|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em| % improper alphabetic constant
    
    \commandbox|{\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em| % file ended while scanning use of \\tcbox
    
   \commandbox|\vrule width 1pt depth 1ex height 1em}| % argument of \lst@temp has an extra }
    
\end{document}



I'd simply use \lstinline{#1} instead of \lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]^#1^. No problem with the braces, because the argument has already been collected with v.

@egreg That's indeed simpler, thanks!
